# How to import local variables of a file to current module

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have this function in my module MetaShrine.py

I am not able to use the local variable `first_name_signup`.
The error is

```
NameError: name 'first_name_signup' is not defined
```

I don't want to make each and every variable global. 
Is there a way I can import local variable of another file without making it global?

This is one of my functions in my main module MetaShrine.py

```
def creating():

    first_name_signup = input("Enter Your First Name\n")
    password_signup = input("Creat a Password\n")
```

When I import this module to a new module, using:

```
from MetaShrine import *

class test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_creating(self):
        self.assertIsInstance(first_name_signup, str)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

... I get this:

```
NameError: name 'first_name_signup' is not defined
```

Comment: On a side note, the test you are writing is redundant because `input` in python3 is always going to return a `str` object. Is this a real test you are writing or its just a dummy code for just this post ?

Comment: just a dummy code. I am getting started with testing so I wanted to learn the syntax and workings of unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, return the value and put it in another variable in the other file. That's the best way I can think of.

```
def creating():

    first_name_signup = input("Enter Your First Name\n")
    password_signup = input("Creat a Password\n")

    return first_name_signup, password_signup
```

Second file:

```
import MetaShrine 

class test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_creating(self):
        first_name_signup, password_signup = MetaShrine.creating()

        self.assertIsInstance(first_name_signup, string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testMetaShrine.py", line 9, in test_creating
    first_name_signup, password_signup = MetaShrine.creating()
AttributeError: type object 'MetaShrine' has no attribute 'creating'

Comment: Then the information in your question isn't accurate, or maybe you put this code in the wrong file? The traceback in your comment looks like you tried to `import MetaShrine` into itself.

Answer (score 0):

i think it was a bad idea to write code in such way. i should have seperated userinput from the functions. putting userinputs on frontend and operations on backend will allow the program to be easily testable.

that is what i did later

Answer (score 0):

I guess the right and pythonic way to write Unit tests in python is to import your `classes`, `methods` and `functions` from your actual module and then run your tests on the imported objects rather than actually importing the `return` values or variables from the module.

So in your case it should look like

***code.py***

```
def creating():

    first_name_signup = input("Enter Your First Name\n")
    password_signup = input("Creat a Password\n")

    return first_name_signup, password_signup
```

**tests.py**

```
import MetaShrine import creating
import unittest

class test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_creating(self):
    # actual assert statement for the test case, i.e.
    result, _ = creating()
    self.assertEqual(result, 'some_name')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```